# Dynamic Inheritance, some piece of code... could you look and help me to improve my code?

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, dynamic-programming

So I have built this piece of code, but it looks like something is wrong in it. Is it not bad practice to creates function which creates class like below?

Should I build some subclasses?

#### base file

```py
class BaseCsvLogger(ABC):
    """The file name is the same for whole working app time.
    """
    # some code ...
    def log_to_file(self, *args):
        ...

class DynamicFileName:
    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.__filename()

class StaticFileName:
    @property
    def filename(self):
        return self.__filename
```

`DynamiclyOpenFile` class has modified log_to_file function to open file just befor `super().log_to_file` and close it just after.
`StatyclyOpened` open file in init method.

## final class creator

```py
from base_logger import DynamicFileName, StaticFilename, BaseCsvLogger


def Logger(filename: Union[str, Callable[[], str]],
           headers: Iterable[str],
           datetime_fmt: str,
           sep: str = ';',
           dec: str = ',',
           open_on_logging: bool = False) -> BaseCsvLogger:

    if open_on_logging:
        baseclass = DynamiclyOpenFile
    else:
        baseclass = StaticlyOpened

    if callable(filename):
        fname_type = DynamicFileName
    else:
        fname_type = StaticFilename

    class LoggerTmp(baseclass, fname_type):
        def __init__(self,
                     filename,
                     headers,
                     datetime_fmt,
                     sep,
                     dec) -> None:
            super().__init__(filename,
                             headers,
                             datetime_fmt,
                             sep, dec)
    logger = LoggerTmp(filename, headers, datetime_fmt, sep, dec)
    return logger
```

Comment: You’re not really needing a new Logger *class* here.  You need a way to specify which existing classes to use in your new logger *instance*.  That is composition/dependency injection.   As per answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than multiple inheritance and a dynamically created class, it would probably be easier to compose the objects using dependency injection. This will lead to less confusing inheritance structures, and more flexible code.

From what I can tell, you need a way to fetch the filename and get a reference to an open file. You can limit this logic to a single dependency that you inject into the `CsvLogger`. In this case you could expose a contextmanager from the dependency, even if it will not close the file in the static case:

```
class FileGetter(ABC):
    def __init__(self, filename: Union[str, Callable[[], str]]):
        self._fname = filename

    @property
    def filename(self) -> str:
        return self._fname() if callable(self._fname) else self._fname

    @contextmanager
    @abstractmethod
    def file(self) -> Iterator[TextIO]:
        ...


class StaticFileGetter(FileGetter):
    def __init__(self, filename: Union[str, Callable[[], str]]):
        super().__init__(filename)
        self._file = open(self.filename, "a")
    
    @contextmanager
    def file(self) -> Iterator[TextIO]:
        yield self._file


class DynamicFileGetter(FileGetter):
    @contextmanager
    def file(self) -> Iterator[TextIO]:
        with open(self.filename, "a") as file:
            yield file
```

Now when designing the `CsvLogger` you can call the dependency to get the instance of the file. In the static case the file is not closed, but it will be closed in the dynamic case:

```
class CsvLogger:
    def __init__(
        self, 
        file_getter: FileGetter, 
        headers, datetime_fmt, sep, dec, ...
    ):
        self._file_getter = file_getter
        ...

    def log_to_file(self, *args):
        with self._file_getter.file() as file:
            ...
```

Constructing the logger now becomes much simpler as well:

```
def csv_logger(
    filename: Union[str, Callable[[], str]],
    headers: Iterable[str],
    datetime_fmt: str,
    sep: str = ';',
    dec: str = ',',
    open_on_logging: bool = False
) -> CsvLogger:
    if open_on_logging:
        file_getter = DynamicFileGetter(filename)
    else:
        file_getter = StaticFileGetter(filename)

    return CsvLogger(file_getter, headers, datetime_fmt, sep, dec)
```